# How to keep neutral silicone?

Tags: silicone

So, I bought this neutral silicone tube to seal a couple of cracks. The tube of silicone is still half full. How do I store it?

Answer (score 5):

Stick a deck or drywall screw in the hole.  Remove it from the applicator.

It will harden up.  When ready to use again, yank out the drywall screw.

Remember silicones have a finite shelf life of only a year, or maybe two if stored in ideal conditions. The worst thing you can possibly do to yourself is try to use a silicone sealant that is too old.  The problem isn't just it failing, but the huge mess of removing all of the faulty product so a new application has a chance!  Silicones are annoyingy hard to remove.

Because of this I am very shy about reusing old silicones unless I am very sure of their provenance.  It's not worth screwing up your project to save half of $5.

Comment: If it is anywhere near the expiration date, test it first, make sure it will harden properly. Old product may not harden. Made this mistake more than once.

Comment: Parenthetically, many tubes have their manufacture date in an obscure format, or it's been scrubbed off the tube by handling. Although I love local businesses, I'll never buy silicone or similar caulk from a mom&pop hardware store.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping some electrical tape tightly around the opening of the tube. A nail inserted into the opening works well too. I've never found those red caps that come with the tubes to do very well.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I will try it out! Thank you